# Does RegexPlanet support capture group references in the replacement string for .NET and, if so, how?

Tags: .net, regex

In the case of the following regex:

```
(.*)in(.*)-in(.*)
```

and the following replacement string:

```
$18888$29999$3
```

the website RegexPlanet seems to be treating some of my capture group references as literals, per http://fiddle.re/8ky3a.

For example, with input `in-in` it produces `$18888$29999` instead of `88889999`, as if the third group matched (to the empty string), but the first two groups did not.

I've tried the following alternate approaches with no success:

Named captures:

```
(?'name'...)       -- Captures, but can't be referenced
(?<name>...)       -- Generates error on site
```

Reference approaches:

```
${n}               -- Where n is the capture group number
${name}
```

I *have* been able to get both unnamed and named capture approaches to work for trivial cases.

Any ideas what's going on? On a related point, can you recommend any alternates to RegexPlanet that support replacement as well as matching?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "in the reference string" - what are you really trying to achieve? Can you demonstrate it in simple C# or VB code, rather than with reference to a single specific website?

Comment: I have no reason to doubt the underlying capability of .NET's regex support and I think I understand it from reading the documentation. My question is really about the website's behavior.  I'm trying to achieve the .NET equivalent of http://fiddle.re/ykf3a  This only came up when I was trying to answer someone else's SO question and wanted to provide a fiddle-like reference.

Comment: Specifically, in the Java case I shared in the previous comment, it includes a column in the results indicating what various "replace" methods return. When I do the same for .NET, there are no such columns.  Perhaps this suggests a lack of support for "replace" on the website for .NET, but then I wonder why they have the "replace" input field.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "replacement string" not "reference string" in the title and initial sentence.

Comment: But we don't know either the input, nor the replacement, nor the regular expression you were using. We really don't have nearly enough context here. Please give us a *concrete example* of what you're trying.

Comment: Feeling a lot of pressure here dealing with the famous Jon Skeet. ;-) I really believe my question is regex independent and the fiddle reference gives an example, for those interested. But I'll update the question itself with an example.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin, I'd guess that RegexPlanet.com is at wrong here if it doesn't replace properly. You could just use a simple `Regex.Replace()` call in for example ideone.com if you don't have easy access to some other compiler. You could use [the example from the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z.aspx) with something like `Regex.Replace("a", @"(?<x>.)", "<${x}>");`

Comment: @PeterAlfvin: The fiddle reference (which should have been in the question, with the text quoted rather than a link - make questions self-contained where possible) gives an example of a regular expression - but not what it was trying to achieve. It would be *much* easier to help you if you'd give an example consisting of the input text, the regular expression, the replacement string, the expected result, and the actual result. As it is, we've got *bits* of it, but no one complete picture.

Comment: @Qtax - Thanks for the ideone suggestion. I was able to determine that I get the same behavior from ideone, so this is really fundamentally about the .NET's regex support and not the RegexPlanet website, at least for everything except possibly support for `(?<name>...)` syntax.

Comment: @Jonskeet - Mea culpa. My rationale was that because I had what I thought was a *generic* issue, I didn't need a *concrete* failure example, but I was obviously wrong on both counts. Thanks for the feedback. I'm going to answer my own question now, after upvoting the one answer I received, since it provided some help.

Comment: @Qtax - I just added the ideone reference to my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RegexPlanet's .NET mechanism is working fine, for the most part. The problem with the above replacement string is that you can't follow a numbered group reference with a digit and have to enclose it with `{}` instead, as in:

```
${1}8888${2}9999$3
```

as shown in this working [fiddle](http://fiddle.re/yxf3a).

Named references work as well, albeit only with `(?'name'...)`, not `(?<name>...)`, and can be referenced with `${name}`. The problem the `<>` named references is perhaps a bug in the site related to its use in the context of HTML.

A working example using `(?<name>...)` can be seen on this [ideone example](http://ideone.com/tLkAAE).

Answer (score 1):

I can't entirely reproduce your problem. When using `(...)` capture groups, `$1` works as a replacement string on regexplanet.com using the .NET engine.

For named captures, though, you seem to be right - `(?<foo>...)` as named capture and `${foo}` as its replacement don't work (I get a message saying `ERROR: error ()`).

Comment: I actually got (?'foo'...) to work just now as well as ${1} for the case of an unnamed group. The wierd behavior I was reporting earlier when nothing worked may have indeed been related to the specific test case I was trying (touche Jon Skeet). I discovered the successes when trying to come up with a trivial example to share here just now.